# How to use foreach inside a function

Tags: php, function, foreach

I am having the darndest time figuring out how to use a `foreach` inside a `function`.I have rewritten my code down to the simplest form and still cannot get it to run. This is the simple version of what I am trying to do:

```
$arr = array("first","second","third");
function myFunction(){
  foreach($arr as $val){
    echo $val.' | ';
  }

}
myFunction();
```

I know the solution must be one of those "doh" moments but I must risk embarrassment 'cause I can't get it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PHP global variables need to be said inside the function. You simply need to say you using a global variable otherwise PHP won't know. So you just need to add `global $arr;` like so:

```
$arr = array("first","second","third");
function myFunction(){
    global $arr; // <-- This states we are using the $arr defined globally.
    foreach($arr as $val){
      echo $val.' | ';
    }
}
myFunction();
```

Comment: Excellent, and I should have known about scope, so I can just put the array inside my function if I don't need it anywhere else?

Comment: @user3762169 Yes, if you don't need it anywhere else you can just define it inside the function.

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = array("first","second","third");
function myFunction($target){
  foreach($target as $val){
    echo $val.' | ';
  }

}
myFunction($arr);//$arr will send to function for process
```

Have a try!

Comment: That worked fine by itself when I ran it but I need to know more about why I need to put the $target parameter in the function. I am going to need to pass about 10 variables into the function for use in my foreach and I'm not sure where $target will come into play there?

Comment: that was my made up name variable. That it parameter the function will need to process, that is a passing variable. There are two method to do that. First like my answer and second is using global variable. You can read this [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_functions.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You can also pass array to the function.

```
 $arr = array("first","second","third");
 function myFunction($arr){
   foreach($arr as $val){ 
     echo $val.' | ';
   }

 }
 myFunction($arr);
```